# How to fix a shift in frequency in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, signals, sampling

I am trying to simulate a nonideal zero-order hold, but I am getting an increase in frequency. Here is my code:

```
amp = 1;
f = 1e9;
fs = 10e9;
phase = 90;
phase = phase/180*pi;
Ts = 1/fs;
start = 0;
cycles = 10;
duration = cycles * Ts;
ts = start:Ts:duration;
vin = amp*cos(2*pi*f*ts + phase);
t = start:0.0001*Ts:duration;
v0 = 0;
vf = vin;
tau = 10e-12;
m = length(t);
n = length(ts);
sections = m/n;
vt = zeros(n,sections);
temp = vector2matrix(t,sections);
for ii = 1:1:n
    for jj = 1:1:sections
        vt(ii,jj) = vf(ii) + (v0 - vf(ii))*exp(-temp(ii,jj)/tau); %ZOH formula
    end
end
vt = vt';
vt = vt(:)';
figure;
plot(t,vt);%xlim([0 0.1e-9]);
hold on
stairs(ts,vf);
hold off
```

In the following image, I am getting the blue trace when it should look something like the orange trace:

[image]

Comment: No, you don't. You're just sampling to slow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a frequency shift, it's because there are not enough samples to follow the blue line. The red curve has

```
ts =1.0e-09 *[0    0.1000    0.2000    0.3000    0.4000    0.5000    0.6000    0.7000    0.8000    0.9000    1.0000]
```

,so it has a lot less points to display the function compared to the blue curve. On these points the blue and red curve coincide, so they are correct. Another way to see this, is to add more points to `ts`. Consider the following code:

```
...
cycles = 12;
duration = cycles * Ts;
ts = start:.8*Ts:duration-.8*Ts;
vin = amp*cos(2*pi*f*ts + phase);
t = start:0.0001*Ts:duration-0.0001*Ts;
...
figure;
plot(t,vt,'k');%xlim([0 0.1e-9]);
hold on
stairs(ts,vf,'y--');
hold off
```

All the code is the same except the number of cycles and the steps for `ts` (now 4 samples longer). The following graph is obtained:

[image]

Now the two nicely overlap, so you can see that there isn't a frequency shift.

Comment: Thank you so much! In my assignment, though, I was asked to sample the signal at the ts time points (rendering the red trace); is there a way to make the blue line follow the red line rather than vice versa?

Comment: @ChristianaS.F.Chamon You can make `t` shorter. maybe something like `t = start:0.1*Ts:duration+9*0.1*Ts;`?